# Tabledrag in grid shape for media form field widget thumbnails

Tags: 7, media, files, javascript

I am looking for a way to change the tabledrag into a grid shape. A nice looking solution for drag-and-drop uploading files and sorting them in a way that jquery sortable does. It should end up to be something like the uploaded thumbnails in Facebook's status update form.

Looks like I'll end up writing a custom solution from scratch like the one here: [jQueryUI Sortable + HTML5 File API examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525795/jqueryui-sortable-html5-file-api-examples)

Can you show me a starting point or do you know about any work has been done so far?

[image]

Comment: Here are some modules that support this behavior:
https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_imagefield_widget
https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload
https://www.drupal.org/project/media_gallery

Answer (score 0):

[Plup](https://www.drupal.org/project/plup) seems a good place to start altough it looks abandoned.

[image: Plup]

Additionally there is [this wiki page](https://groups.drupal.org/node/155764) for comparison of similar modules.